# Partitions not visible while dual booting Kali with Windows 11 with GPT disk

Tags: partition, kali-linux, dual-boot, gpt, partition-table

While trying to install Kali Linux as a secondary OS with Windows 11(primary OS), the partition created for Kali is not visible during the Graphical Install.
The hard drive I'm trying to install kali on is of size 1 TB. Even after making a partition of 150 GB, the disk partition menu in the graphical install of kali is not showing the partitions rather showing the disk with one partition of size 932 GB
Upon initial research, I tried fixing the partition table using gdisk (since my system has GPT disks), but that didn't help.
Primary OS: Windows 11
Disk Type: GPT
Image Used: kali-linux-2021.4a-installer-amd64

**EDITED:**
Disk Management:
[image]

Partition Not Visible:
[image]

Comment: How does the disk show when you choose 'try Kali' in GParted? Did you make the 150 Gb partition in Windows? Did you leave it unformatted ( since you cannot format it as EXT4 in Windows )?

Comment: Has Windows 11 partitioned the disk using Windows Storage Spaces (sort of a Windows equivalent of Linux LVM, but incompatible)? Could you show a `gdisk -l` output of the hard drive?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not familiar with Gparted. Yes, I made a 150 GB partition in windows. Yes, I've formatted it in NTFS since only two options are available NTFS and FAT. @JoepieEs

Comment: @telcoM No, i've used `disk management` tool. I'm sorry I don't know how to use `gdisk -l`. I've added related images in the question.

Comment: the dynamic disk is the issue here i guess?

Comment: The dynamic disk seems to be exactly the issue here. The disk management tool created a Dynamic Disk "logical volume" within the 1.0 TB "LDM data partition". But Kali's installer does not support Windows dynamic disks, so it cannot see that.

Answer (score 0):

I would delete all partitions on the 1 TB disk (in Windows, so that everything is unallocated).

Then make a `/root` partition (1 GB would be sufficient FAT32), a `/` (boot) partition for your Kali installation (100-150 GB EXT4 (and if you want to install another Linux distribution in the future make it e.g. 200 GB), so you can resize it and make another partition for that distro) and a `/home` partition for your documents/photos/music/videos/downloads (EXT4, size it for your needs). If you ever need to reinstall Kali or you want to use another Linux based system, you can install that without losing any data.

Linux distros can read and write to NTFS partitions. Windows cannot read EXT4 partitions without third party software.

So you could make another NTFS-partition for your documents etc. so you can move those from your Windows installation to your big HD. So if you ever need to reinstall Windows your documents etc. are secure on the other disk.

You can partition the disk during the installation of Kali, or do while trying out Kali with GParted (it is about the same as PartitionMagic was) and is not difficult to use.